# how to split a string at special symbol in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I have this string:

```
  x = "G5.jpg']"
```

and I wish to split it at the symbol `'` so that then I have `G5.jpg` and `]` seperately in a list. Anyone has an idea how to do this? I have tried this:

```
    name = x.split["'"]
```

but it doesnt split the string. I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Just... split on `'`? `name = x.split("'")`

Comment: sorry I updated the question, this is what I had tried

Comment: @AndromachiiiRozakiii Nope it's still wrong

Comment: You're using square brackets instead of parentheses. They're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
x = "G5.jpg']"
name = x.split("'") # name = ["G5.jpg", "]"
# To get only the "G5.jpg" use this:
name = x.split("'") [0]
```

In your code you have `x.split["'"]` - This is incorrect syntax.

Comment: hello, sorry for the confusion! I updated my question, I had tried exactly that initially

Comment: @AndromachiiiRozakiii Updated

Answer (score 0):

Calling `x.split("'")` will return a list. You just then simply take the first element from that returned list

```
x = "G5.jpg']"
parts = x.split("'")
# parts now == ['G5.jpg', ']']
name = parts[0]
# name now == 'G5.jpg'
```

Comment: hello, sorry for the confusion! I updated my question, I had tried exactly that initially

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) to return all captured matches:

```
import re
x = "G5.jpg']"
name = re.findall(r"[^']+", x)
print(name)
# ['G5.jpg', ']']
```